# Why is TCP receive window a multiple of MSS?

Tags: tcp

Why is TCP receive window considered to be a multiple of MSS Maximum Segment Size?

[Wiki](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/TCP_Receive_Window) states that in order to fully utilize the packet lengths and avoid IP fragmentation , an integral multiple of the Maximum Segment Size (MSS) is generally recommended for the receive window and the value is therefore often only given as a factor/multiple.

[Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_segment_size#MSS_and_MTU) it is stated that segments exceeding the MSS size is discarded.

Answer (score 1):

For alignment... ergo it fits in a nic buffer on [ROM] @ a place in its memory which is then what you read from via a port or DMA